# How can i show the scanned bluetooth devices in the Listview?

Tags: android, bluetooth, device

That's my scan method:

```
public void scan(View view) {

    if (BA.isDiscovering()) {
        BA.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    BA.startDiscovery();//startet die Suche

    //broadcastreceiver
    SingBroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new SingBroadcastReceiver();
    IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, ifilter);

}
```

and my `BroadcastReceive` class:

```
private class SingBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Intent welches wir empfangen
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Bluetoothdevice objekte vom intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // Speichert den Namen und die Adresse des Geräts in einen Array Adapter und ziegt diese in einem Toast an
            String derp = device.getName() + " - " + device.getAddress();
            Toast.makeText(context, derp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //zeigt Bluetoothgeräte in der nähe als toast

            //TO DO: geräte in Liste ausgeben
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem:** It just show it in a `Toast` and not in a `List view`.

Comment: why don`t you start capturing device information in some data structure that you are receiving onReceive method and pass this information to listadapter to show.

Comment: ok, but how shall i do this? i am new at programming android :/